# Shadow Root? Calling out stroke color

Tags: svg, colors, stroke

I am calling out a stroke in an SVG, it works if I don't put any class on the style. But I need to put it there because needed to be fixable for the end user to pick any color they want.

```css
symbol#icon-arrow{
  stroke: #ff6600;
  } /*this is working*/
  
 
 .icon-orange symbol#icon-arrow{
  stroke: #99CA3D;
  } /*this is not working, but this is what I need*/
```

```html
<div id="icon-load" style="display:none;"></div>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
                  <symbol id="icon-arrow" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="arcs" >
                      <path class="arrow" d="M12 19V6M5 12l7-7 7 7"/>
                  </symbol>
              </svg>
              
              

              <a href="#" class="icon">
                  <svg class="icon icon-orange"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg>
              </a>
```

Comment: Seminal article on this at at https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/ css variables are now gaining ground in newest browsers too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @enxaneta said, you have to style the `<use>` element, and let the colour percolate down to the symbol.

But you'll first need to remove the `stroke` attribute from the symbol. Otherwise that presentation attribute will override the colour you want it to inherit.

```css
.icon-orange use {
  stroke: #ff6600;
}
  
.icon-green use {
  stroke: #99CA3D;
}
```

```html
<div id="icon-load" style="display:none;"></div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
    <symbol id="icon-arrow" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="arcs" >
        <path class="arrow" d="M12 19V6M5 12l7-7 7 7"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
              
<a href="#" class="icon">
    <svg class="icon icon-orange"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg>
</a>

<a href="#" class="icon">
    <svg class="icon icon-green"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explain!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `.icon-orange` there is a `<use>` element. You have to style the use element. However if you need to refer the #icon-arrow here is how you can do it:

```css
 /*declare the namespace xlink*/
 @namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
 /*style the use element inside the icon-orange whose's xlink:herf attribute is  the icon arrow*/
 .icon-orange use[xlink|href ="#icon-arrow" ]{
  stroke: #99CA3D;
  }
```

```html
<div id="icon-load" style="display:none;"></div>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
                  <symbol id="icon-arrow" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"  stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="arcs" >
                      <path class="arrow" d="M12 19V6M5 12l7-7 7 7"/>
                  </symbol>
              </svg>
              
              

              <a href="#" class="icon">
                  <svg class="icon icon-orange"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow" width="24" height="24"></use></svg>
              </a>
```

Comment: is make sense, but when I copy it over, it didn't do anything? https://codepen.io/yyanmak/pen/wbmwvY

Comment: This is a fork of your pen: please note that the symbol has no stroke and the use has a width and a height: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/yWKOOB

Comment: Thank you for your help!